# Easy and fast way to map values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to map a list of categories from a desktop site to the matching mobile categories.
It's need to be done on client with JavaScript on every page, so it should be quiet fast.

So i started with this:

```
var mapDesktop2Mobile = [{"news":"panorama"}, {"local":"someothercat"}];
```

now i want to get returned "panorama", if my desktop category is "news".

How can i get value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Although it would make more sense to just create a single object instead of an array of objects. Then you can access the property directly, now you have to iterate over the array first.

Comment: P.S. That's not JSON.  It's a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be fast you shouldn't nest the object (which acts as a dictionary) in an array, but just use an object:

```
var mapDesktop2Mobile = {"news":"panorama", "local":"someothercat"};
```

At that point you can get the value with:

```
mapDesktop2Mobile["news"]
```

If you need a dictionary of more complex objects you can use the value of a **UNIQUE** property as the key, much like this:

```
var complexDictionary = {
    "key01" : { "name" : "key01", "property1" : 1, "property2" : 4 },
    "key02" : { "name" : "key02", "property1" : 2, "property2" : 3 },
    "key03" : { "name" : "key03", "property1" : 3, "property2" : 2 },
    "key40" : { "name" : "key40", "property1" : 4, "property2" : 1 }
};
```

The fact that you repeat the property as a key should be of no concern, you won't allocate much more memory and leverage the full speed of the VM implementation (mostly with hashes, buckets and native platform code -- you can't hope to get any faster than that).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an array for your map?  Don't.  Use an object with multiple properties.

```
var mapDesktop2Mobile = {
    "news":"panorama",
    "local":"someothercat"
};
```

Then you can simply do `mapDesktop2Mobile.news` (or `mapDesktop2Mobile['news']`).